# Magento error: Unable to create directory '/var/www/html/magento/media/tmp/catalog/product'

Tags: php, magento, image-uploading

When adding images for new products to my magento store I get the error:

```
Unable to create directory '/var/www/html/magento/media/tmp/catalog/product'.
```

Now, I have made sure file permissions are set to 777, so I am wondering why is this happening and how can I fix this ?

**UPDATE**
Tried everything suggested below to no avail. I get the error:
    Destination folder is not writable or does not exists.

well, this is a lie. As for a temporary basis I have set all folders and files within the magento folder to have world write permission (777). Are the directory locations stored in some configuration file ? or what else could be causing this ? Been pulling my hair out over last week trying to solve this!

Comment: To what folder you set permissions? Try to set permissions recursively

Comment: I have set permission recursively to the magento folder, and looking within at folders they all show as having 777 permissions.

Comment: You must NOT set  777 for whole Magento files.

Comment: Ohhh, could you direct me as how to set the permissions correctly

Comment: Check this out http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Comment: Tried that and failed. The error is still persisting

Comment: Just make the directory manually and give it write permissions for your web server user, it'll probably stop the issue anyway

Comment: Have done to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an issue with SELINUX:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/magentofoldername/*

chmod -R a+w /var/www/html/magentofoldername/*
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, pub ownership was set to root so I just changed it to www-data:www-data and it worked. And instead of +777 permission +755 would be better.